# pathfinder intersect fails to capture intersecting shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

When I perform Pathfinder Intersect in Illustrator, a significant slice of the intersecting shape is left out.

I've intersected dozens of outlined letters like this, but it's not working on the letter "n" from the Indie Flower font.

All of these shapes have a fill and no stroke.

I'm using CS6.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not "missing" part. Rather it appears to either be aligning pixels (Check Align to Pixel grid), or simplifying the path (check Pathfinder Options), I won't bother asking *why*. I assume there's some reason merely outlining the characters is insufficient.

Comment: Turning off align to pixel grid worked! Thanks.  I'm cutting up the outlined letters so that I can reveal the width transitions in the correct sequence with SVG masks.  Thanks again.